# How to use Grape with Oracle driver?

Tags: oracle, groovy, groovy-grape

In my groovy script, I have this code :

```
@Grapes([
 @Grab(group='com.oracle', module='ojdbc14', version='10.2.0.3.0')
])
```

When I run the script, I receive an error message :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed:     com.oracle#ojdbc14;10.2.0.3.0!ojdbc14.jar]
```

So, I download the jar file from oracle and I add it to my maven  repository :

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.0.3.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=\path\to\ojdbc14.jar
```

I try again and I receive the same error message

I add a config file as describe on the [grape page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape) , with a ibiblio refering to my local repository, I try again and have also the same error.

I tried with another group like jfreechart and it is working.

So, why is it not working with ojdbc14.jar

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

After a cleaning of the local maven repository and grape directory, it's working fine now.
The problem became from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that you have to add the local Maven repository according with Grape documentation ([link to documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape)).

Section from documentation:

> If you find yourself wanting to reuse artifacts that you already have locally in your Maven2 repository, then you can add this line to your ~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml:

```
<ibiblio name="local" root="file:${user.home}/.m2/repository/" m2compatible="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add ext='pom' to your @Grab.

@Grab(group='com.oracle', module='ojdbc14', version='10.2.0.3.0', ext='pom')

that's ok.